# Single value of raster displays as transparent?

Tags: qgis, raster, style

I have a GeoTiff raster that I'm trying to style, but a single value (1 of 8) refuses to take on any color. It always displays as transparent. Any idea of why this is / how to resolve it?

Working in QGIS 2.14/GDAL/GRASS.

Comment: Are you using the "singleband pseudocolor" option? If you're classifying the colors by equal interval, you should be able to double-click the color of that value and change it through a color picker.

Comment: I am. I've tired that, the linear option, discrete intervals, exact intervals, building my own .qml file, etc. -- but for some reason whichever raster tiles take on "1" values display as transparent... no matter what I do.

Comment: This strikes me as being one of two possible things, but I can certainly be mistaken; 1) The NoData value of your raster is 1. I'm pretty sure you can't style NoData/NULLs in QGIS. or 2) There may be 0's and 2's but there aren't any 1 values in your raster. Without seeing the data, it's hard to say.

Comment: The nodata value is on the order of magnitude xx * 10^32, so I don't think it's that... and there are 1's because when I load the raw raster it displays. I think it was something with the .qml file I've been trying to apply. I built it from scratch, but am building one now off of QGIS-generated classes (and then altering colors). Hope that works out the kinks.

Comment: That worked -- guess it's best to use Q's auto-generation algorithms and then adjust whenever possible. Thanks very much for your suggestions/input!